# Show div once clicked and hide when clicking outside it

Tags: jquery, click

This question has been asked multiple times, however none of the answers seem to work for me.
I want the div to be display when click on the link
Then click outside of it, div Hide

[my code](http://jsfiddle.net/4yBGt/179/)

html:

```
<a href="#" id='link'>Click here to show div</a>
```

js:

```
 $('#link').click(function(e) {
    $('div.termifier').remove();
    $('<div>').addClass('termifier').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: event.pageY ,
        left: event.pageX ,
        display: 'none'
        }).appendTo('body')
    .append(
        $('<div>').html("termifier")
     );
     $('div.termifier').fadeIn('slow');
 });

$('html').click(function() {
    $('div.termifier').fadeOut();
 });

 $('div.termifier').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

css

```
div.termifier {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  width: 256px;
  color: brown;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `e.stopPropagation()`

```
$('#link').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    /* Rest of the code for clicking */
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yBGt/182/)

If you want to prevent the fade when you click the div aswell, do this:

```
 $(document.body).bind('click','.termifier',function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

You can use `.on()` instead of `.bind()` if you were to use a newer version of jQuery than 1.6.4

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4yBGt/186/)

Comment: when I click link, div is not displayed

Comment: Did you try the jsFiddles i linked?

Comment: @naser That is because event.pageX is undefined use e.pageX instead look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4yBGt/187/

Comment: @naser Do not edit the code like that, it should not end with }); rest of the code should be in that event....